# How to update cache memory when record is updated?

Tags: cakephp

> How to update cache memory when record is updated?
>
> ### like afterSave in Model we can update cache after record save?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could clear the cache via [Cache::clear()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html#Cache%3a%3aclear) if that's what you try to acheive.

Answer (score 1):

In Model class in cakephp, only two callbacks are there for this purpose afterSave and afterDelete  Ref:([Callback](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html)) . You should clear or delete  your cache in these two after record created or deleted from db Ref:[Caching Helper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html).

But these doesn't work well with updateAll or deleteAll function when record is being updated , so you need to clear cache in Controller file every time you update in any record.